# Problem in integrating Wordpress blog's in Cakephp Website

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, integration

I was working on a site of Cakephp which was successfully delivered.But recently Client again appered and asked me to put the Wordpress blog in it,to cover up the Blogging thing in his site.He wants to share the authentication between the Cakephp and WP.Whoever registers in his site,then Logins in it and if he clicks on the Blog Tab,he must be redirected to the WP blog with the session still there.After some googling I have installed it in /app/webroot/blog folder but I am not able to edit the .htaccess file.
Please help me in the right direction,that how to share the authentication betwenn Cake Php and Wordpress, and the second one how to customize the .htaccess file so that URL's look good.
 Thanks in advance..!

Comment: The technology you are looking for is called "Single Sign On". I don't know of any solution integrating WP and Cake, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. In CakePHP you can have access to multiple databases. Why not configure cake to have access to WP and use their login on the entire website? You can link the user information to the ID in the WP database and tie it to the content in the CakePHP specific database. Since you are using CakePHP, this should actually be quite simple too.

Comment: Seconded.  Be careful of how each app hashes passwords, though.

One other option would be to have a link from your Cake site that will redirect you to an auto-login script (use tokens) which will establish the credentials for the WP site (you'll need to know how WP checks for a login, then imitate it).

Comment: Thirded. You just need to be really careful with Wordpress upgrades, as their scheme may change.

Comment: save yourself some time and headache and convince client that it is not very good idea. mention security, future upgrades of WP, 2 systems build to function independently, etc.